# Tkinter: Don't push the undo stack on delete text on tk.Text widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am using Tkinter and Python3.7.
I want to don't push record to stack of undo.
tk.Text widget's delete method is do push stack on called it.

```py
self.text_widget.delete(1.0, 'end')   # push stack!
```

But this is not needed in my program. How to do it?

Comment: If you are using `tk.Entry`, you may could bind `StringVar` for it.

Comment: Are you intending to use the undo feature at all?  If not, then the normal state of the Text widget is to not push *anything* on the undo stack.  If you are, then every change has to be pushed, as otherwise it might not be possible to apply previous changes, as they'd be referring to text that no longer exists.

Comment: Yes. I want to use `edit_undo` method of `Text` widget. But case of `delete` method, I want don't push stack of undo.